# Elastic Seach - filter top N documents by score and then sort by field

Tags: c#, sorting, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I'm using Elastic Search with Nest 5.6, I would like to filter only 100 documents with the highest Score **and then** sort by any other field. The problem is that sorting is done together between the score and the field, but I'd like to sort ONLY the TOP (N) records with the highest score.
For example, ordering by Score and the lower value of the item results in the table below:

- **Score** | **Item Value**
- 0.8 | 7.0
- 0.8 | 8.0
- 0.7 | 6.0   - **this price shold be the first.**

My query follows below:

```
 client.Search<ItemDto>(s => s
           .From(0)
           .Size(100)
           .Index(INDEX)
           .Query(q => q                        
              .Bool(b => b.Must(query)))
          .Sort(y=>y
            .Descending(SortSpecialField.Score)
            .Field(f=>f.Field(new Field("itemValue")).Ascending())
          ));
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem recently myself. Here's the issue you run into with this:

**Sharding**: Each index is made up of some number of shards helping you to distribute your index across nodes. But this also means getting exact counts for anything in the middle of the pipeline is super dicey. This is the reason that bucketed aggregations only give you approximations for your top results. It's running calculations against the shards individually and combining them intelligently.

Here's what I ended up doing -- and remember, this isn't going going to be exact because as far as I know there's not really a great way to do this.

Use a [Sampler Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-sampler-aggregation.html) to pull (approximately) the top 100. You'll specify the Shard Size to be the number of results returned divided by the number of shards. So say you have 5 shards (the default), you request 20 documents from each shard.

Then inside that sampler aggregation, you can add a [Top Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to actually get your source documents and also to sort them as you wish.

```
new SamplerAggregation("sampler_aggregation")
{
    ShardSize = maxResults / SHARD_NUMBER,
    Aggregations = new TopHitsAggregation("top_hits")
    {
        Sort = {Whatever},
        Size = maxResults
    }
}
```

Then To Access Your Documents

```
searchResponse.Aggs.Sampler("sampler_aggregation")
                   .TopHits("top_hits")
                   .Documents<YourType>().ToArray()
```

---

**HOWEVER: If you're super set on getting very exact results, you're better off just sorting by relevance and grabbing the top 100. Then just sort the results again in memory.**